# Why does std::locale loc("en_US") throw an exception?

Tags: c++, locale

I attempting to instantiate a `std::locale` object with the American or British locale string.
Both `std::locale loc("en_US")` and `std::locale loc("en_GB")` throw a *bad locale name* runtime exception. Creating a locale using `""` or `"C"` works fine; however, I'm having trouble setting an individual country locale.

The reason I'd like to do this is for unit testing purposes, to make sure a collection of string sorting methods work correctly.

I should also point out that I'm coding in Windows using Visual Studio 2008 and I'd like to keep my code cross-platform, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

The strings which `std::locale` supports are implementation specific; it could be that implementation doesn't support the string you are passing as argument.

Since you are programming in Windows, you can be interested to [Language Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf.aspx), which lists the language identifiers used by `setlocal`, and [Country/Region Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z.aspx) for the country identifiers. As far as I can see, the language identifiers use a hyphen (e.g. *en-US*, *nl-BE*, and *zh-HK*).

You can find more information on [std::locale::global(std::locale("zh-CN")) Gets "Bad locale name"??](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0fb287af-bb58-4c60-a3da-14fe84c16948)

Comment: I've noticed that my VC++ Express 2012 now accepts "en-US" but still throws on "en_US".

Answer (score 5):

You better use boost.locale that uses ICU library for this. ICU provides many locales and is not dependent on OS you use. To generate std::locale you need to write:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("en_US");
```

For more information:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0_b1/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html